# SilverStripe - changing the full URL of child page removing the prefix from parent page

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am working on a SilverStripe project. In my project, I have a page that has a child page like this.

[image]

In the picture, both the Contact Us page and Contact Us Success page have the same page type, Page. The contact us page URL is {base-url}/contact-us. The success page URL is {base-url}/contact-us/success. Since the contact us page's URL segment is "contact-us", the contact us success page has the prefix, "contact-us". What I would like to do is that I would like to change the URL of the success page to this, {base-url}/contact-success removing the 'contact-us' page. Within the CMS, I can only change the last segment of the URL. I am not allowed to change the prefix. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to move the page to the top of the Tree. Or make a virtual page that points to Contact Success Page